# When i print image in php it don't show its full width, cut from right side

Tags: html, css

```
@page {
    size: landscape;
    margin: 0;
}

@media print {
    .noprint{
        display: none;
    }
    #main_col{
        background-image: url('images/cavec_new_cert.jpg') !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-size: 842px !important;
        margin-top: -100px !important;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        margin-left: -180px !important;
        margin-right: 0px !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    }
    html, body {
      height:100vh;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

when i print the image its looks like cut from right side or it show in a box, it don't show the full image

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the `#main_col` is big enough to fit the image? Have you tried using your print css in browser by setting `media emulate print`?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the inspector of page and check where is issue.
I think It's due to small width of div 'main_col' you need to increase it.
OR
Change css of #main_col with this code of css:

```
#main_col{
 background: url(images/cavec_new_cert.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 }
```

Hope this will work, waiting for your feedback.
Thanks :)